# Wordpress no more categories for my translated product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wpml

There is somehting strange on my website. I'm using wordpress, woocommerce and wpml. I got 5 languages et some products. It appears that some translated products lost their categories.

So i find the solution by just "update the product" they get their categories back but i need to do it for many many many products.

Is there a solution in wordpress to update all product ? no modify just update.

Comment: Your question is not answerable. Better ask super efficient WPML support as StackOverFlow doesn't handle any software support…

Comment: Ok i was sure there was some php to force product to update but nvm